# Why does std::basic_ios have a public constructor?

Tags: c++, stream, language-lawyer

[`std::basic_ios` has a public constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/basic_ios):

```
explicit basic_ios (std::basic_streambuf<CharT,Traits>* sb);
```

IMO, the sole reason for a class to have a public constructor is to use a standalone instance of that class in a program.  If a class exists only to have other classes descend from it (as seems to be the case for `basic_ios`), all of the class's constructors should be `protected`.  The constructors of `std::ios_base` are all protected.  But, for some reason, the designers of the standard made this one constructor of `basic_ios` public.

`basic_ios` is used as a base class for several stream types, and I can't envision a use case where you'd have one that wasn't at least a `basic_istream` or `basic_ostream`.  Is there one?

Answer (score 1):

The other reason for a class to have a public constructor is to have this constructor signature available to construct a derived object:

```
struct B{
  B(int);
  protected:
  ~B();
  };

 struct A:B{
    private://no effect.
    using B::B;

    public:
    A(void*);
    };

 A a(10);
```

The constructor must be public in the base class because a using declaration of a base constructor does not change the accessibility of the inherited constructor.

Comment: Seems resonable, except afaik, the `basic_ios` ctor taking a `basic_streambuf*` has been public since before you could do `using B::B;`. I expect that old implementations just had a proxy ctor: `A(int x) : B(x) {}` - which works fine even if `B`'s ctor is `protected`.

Answer (score 0):

What I failed to notice was that `std::basic_istream`, `std::basic_ostream` and `std::basic_iostream` also had public constructors (each takes a `std::basic_streambuf*`).

This allows for a generic-programming analogue of polymorphism, in the same vein as the pimpl idiom.

That is, this way you can create a specialized streambuf type and use it in a `basic_`[io]`stream` without having to create specialized stream classes. (The functionality is limited: You can't assign a new buffer to the same stream, and you have to externally keep track of the buffer's lifetime and ownership).

The specialized `basic_`[io]`fstream` and `basic_`[io]`stringstream` each contain a full instance of the associated buffer type.  This means an instance of a specialized stream type will only work with its internal buffer and not another, not even one of the same type.  Using a raw `basic_`[io]`stream` is a (clunky) workaround to this.

```
template<class C, class TR>
class snazzy_filebuf: public std::basic_streambuf<C, TR>
{
 protected:
   typename TR::int_type overflow(TR::int_type) override;
   typename TR::int_type underflow(TR::int_type) override;
   typename TR::int_type pbackfail(TR::int_type) override;
 public:
   snazzy_filebuf();
};

.....
snazzy_filebuf<char> buf;
std::basic_ostream<char> o_s(&buf); 

o_s << "Hello, world\n";
```